# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getOppty(Id) from the type classname (108:19)

Tags: apex, query, method, refactoring

**I want to do a refactor from this map, so I try with a method, this is how I try:**

```
private static Map<Id,Opportunity> getOppty (Set<Id> solutionId) {
  Map<Id, Opportunity> oppties = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
    [
      SELECT
        Name,
        Id,
        CloseDate,
        Estimated_Sales_Value__c,
        Solution__r.Name,
        Distributor__c
      FROM Opportunity
      WHERE Solution__c = :solutionId
    ]
  );
  return oppties;
}
```

**This is the original**

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppties = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
         [
           SELECT
             Name,
             Id,
             CloseDate,
             Estimated_Sales_Value__c,
             Solution__r.Name,
             Distributor__c
           FROM Opportunity
           WHERE Solution__c = :solutionId
         ]
       );
```

but I get the following errors:

> Error  classname  Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getOppty(Id) from the type classname (108:19)

**someone can help me in this please?
I'm new in this, I want to know which is my error**

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. Where is the actual method declaration?  You just have statements in your OP

Comment: I see no difference in the code snippets that you provided, except that you included the `return` statement in the first one. Are you sure that you didn't copy/paste the same thing twice? | I agree with copredy: post more code. `getOppty()` is nowhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Never mind about my last sentence. You incorrectly used the triple backticks at the beginning of your code block: they need to be separated from the first line or else the first line might not appear. It's been fixed. But I still don't see what you are trying to do differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is providing you with some good, albeit subtle, information.

In programming, data types matter. A `Set<Id>` is different from an `Id`, which is different from an `Integer`, etc... and in most occasions, they're not interchangeable.

You declared your method as
`private static Map<Id,Opportunity> getOppty (Set<Id> solutionId)`

When you call that method, it expects you to pass it a `Set<Id>` and nothing else. If you pass it something different, you'll get an error.

Based on your error, I think you're calling this method like

```
Id myId = '001000000000000AAA';
Classname.getOppty(myId);
```

You're trying to pass a single Id instance instead of a `Set<Id>`. Since you didn't write any method that accepts a single Id, you get an error.

You can fix this in one of two ways:

- Pass a `Set<Id>` to your method, even if it only has a single Id in it (the important part is that you're passing a `Set<Id>`)

  - `Classname.getOppty(new Set<Id>{myId});`
- Change your method signature to accept a single Id instance as an argument

  - `private static Map<Id,Opportunity> getOppty (Id solutionId) {`

Also be aware that by declaring your method as `static`, you need to call it using the class name, and not from an instance of your class. The private visibility modifier also makes it so that you can only call your method from within your `Classname` class itself.

Wrong

```
Classname classInstance = new Classname();
classInstance.myStaticMethod();
```

Correct

```
Classname.myStaticMethod();
```